# Can I upgrade php to php56 on aws ec2 using puppet and not logging in and using yum?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, puppet, upgrade

Apparently if you use puppet to require "php" and you have version 5.3 installed, then even if your yum repos have 5.6 php packages, requiring "php56" will not perform an upgrade.  All the docs I read say to log into the node and use sudo and yum to remove the existing php packages and replace them with 5.6.  These nodes are in production and I would like to use puppet to upgrade my php.  Anyone have experience in this?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, Puppet will only upgrade packages if you use a resource such as the following:

```
# always update to the latest version
package { 'php':
  ensure => 'latest',
}

# update (or revert) to a specific version
package { 'php':
  ensure => '5.6',
}
```

Note that in the latter case, the given version must exactly match the label on the package, e.g. `5.6.24+dfsg-0+deb8u1` on Debian 8.

Since you're probably using a Forge module to manage PHP (you should), you need to check that module's capabilities to override the appropriate `ensure` value(s).

If none, you can resort to a minor hack using a [resource collector](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_collectors.html):

```
Package<| title == "php" |> { ensure => 'latest' }
```

This has same caveats, but might just suffice for your use case.

Whatever you do, test the code carefully before throwing it at your entire production environment.